# Sum Algorithm: O(n^2) in average

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have `n` numbers (could be a `list` or `array` of `n` numbers).

Given a number `k` I want to return a quadruplet of numbers (`a,b,c,d`) thus that
`a+b+c+d=k`.

Time Complexity: `O(n^2)` in average (probability).

Comment: Doesn't seem like something you'd want to do

Comment: Use a hash table to hash the sum of all pairs of numbers. Then for each pair, check how many times `k - sum of that pair` appears in your hash table, and increment the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Think about how to break the problem into subproblems.